# Как в tar создать архив в той же папке одной командой?

Tags: windows-10, tar

Как создать архив в той же папке, заархивировав в него все файлы из этой папки? Пробовал так:

```
tar -czf "{folder}\\archive.tar.gz" -C "{folder}" .
```

Но эта команда выдает

> tar: Failed to clean up compressor

Как создать архив в папке `folder`, не находясь в `folder` (не переходя с помощью `cd`) из файлов, находящихся в `folder`?

Comment: У вас tar пытается заархивировать файл в самого себя. Исключите файл `archive.tar.gz` из списка файлов на архивирование. Ну и не проще ли сделать архив в другой папке, а потом переместить?

Comment: @AlexeyTen исключил. Добавил --exclude="{folder}\\archive.tar.gz" Та же ошибка. Уже пытался слделать архив в другой папке командой

tar -czf "{folder2}\\archive.tar.gz" -C "{folder}" .

Но она выдает tar: can`t chdir to "{folder}"

Comment: Как-то так: tar -czf archive.tar.gz /path/to/folder/*